# How to delete a table that is corrupted when copying another table in Access Web App?

Tags: microsoft-access

This question is specific to an Access Web App, hosted on my institutional Sharepoint / Office 365 account. I copied a table, "Equipment" by dragging and dropping it using the Navigation Pane in the Access 2013 editor. After doing so, Access crashed. When I open my application for design now, the other tables are still there, and apparently their data, views and relationships are intact. They are also working on the client side in the browser.

However, I have a "broken" table with a name of "Copy of Equipment." The table does not have any views. Here are the symptoms when I try options on the table in Access 2013 editor:

- "edit table" -> no response at all (no error message)
- "view data" -> A new tab appears that is blank with two buttons (a plus sign and trash can). An error window pops up that says `Access Services` `The record source Copy of Equipment specified on this view does not exist.` `TECHNICAL DETAILS` `OK`.

  - When I click on `TECHNICAL DETAILS` I get a `Correlation ID: <long hex code>` and a date and time.
- When I right click on the new tab and choose "design view" Access 2013 crashes.

Does anyone know how I can delete this table? If you're familiar with Access Web Apps, at least at this point, you'll know that the options available in Access 2013 editor are far more limited than with a desktop database. I am wondering if there is possibly a trick for deleting this table, although I suspect that any method would require a different application to connect to the database, and probably some privileges that I don't have with my user account to our Office 365 site.  Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: I found a workaround (that seems buggy) to delete the table. Another table "Actions" had a lookup in the original "Equipment" table. I changed the settings on that lookup to allow for deletion from the equipment table. After doing this I was able to delete the "Copy of Equipment" table. This seems buggy to me, since there were no tables that had lookups to "Copy of Equipment." A lesson learned for now is not to copy a table in an Access App by dragging and dropping.

Comment: And oh, wow, did I speak to soon. Deleting "Copy of Equipment" table has made things worse. Now the existing tables are corrupted. I'll go ahead and leave this little story here so hopefully someone else doesn't make the same mistake.